# Creating a button with a dialog in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I want to make a Button.

I have a EDT "Resigning", which can't be edited, it only can be edited once and that when I press the button. 
When clicking the button a Dialog shall Pop up where I can type in the date.

I have to write a class I think, but I am struggling a lot...

With Kind Regards

Khashayar

Answer (score 1):

you can write the code in `clicked` method of the button.

*Here a simple job to do that:*

```
static void StackOverflow(Args _args)
{
    Dialog                     dialog;
    DialogField                dialogDate;
    date                       newDate;    
    ;
    dialog     = new Dialog("Set new date");
    dialogDate = dialog.addField(ExtendedTypeStr("YourEDTName"), "New date:");        
    if (dialog.run())
    {    
        newDate = dialogDate.value(); //Get value of new date.        
        //Here code to update your table                
    }
}
```

Comment: I added to the last if-clause "EmploymentTable.Resigning = dialogDate.value();" . I am still able to overwrite the resigning date when I click the buttom for the same record. 
How can Change that so I can't Change it, even i click the buttom again for the same record. TTSBegin?, with if clause ?

Comment: if you have an error for `EmploymentTable.update()` yes need `ttsBegin and ttsCommit`. Try this `select forupdate from EmploymentTable where...` then `ttsbegin; EmploymentTable.update(); ttscommit; `

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from overwriting existing value you can modify your method as following:

```
public void clicked()
{
    Dialog                     dialog;
    DialogField                dialogDate;
    date                       newDate;    
    ;

    if (EmploymentTable.Resigning == dateNull())
    {
        dialog     = new Dialog("Set new date");
        dialogDate = dialog.addField(ExtendedTypeStr("YourEDTName"), "New date:");        
        if (dialog.run())
        {    
            newDate = dialogDate.value(); //Get value of new date.        
            //Here code to update your table                
        }
    }
    else
    {
        warning("Value already exists.");
    }
}
```

The code above is checking whether value already exists, before allowing to assign new value.

More better approach is disabling the button if value already exists. To do this write a method to disable/enable your button and call it in `active` method on form datasource.

Comment: unfortunately I still have Problems. All the codes help me to work with the button, but once again...after entrying a date, I still can Change it.

Comment: void clicked() {    SycResigning        resigning;
    SycEmploymentTable  EmploymentTable;
    Dialog              dialog;
    DialogField         dialogDate;
    date                NewDate;
    super()
    ;

    if (EmploymentTable.Resigning == dateNull())
    {
        dialog     = new Dialog("Set new date");
        dialogDate = dialog.addField(ExtendedTypeStr(SycResigning), "New date:");

Comment: if (dialog.run())
        {
            newDate = dialogDate.value(); //Get value of new date.

            //Here code to update your table
            SycEmploymentTable.Resigning = dialogDate.value();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        warning("Value already exists.");
    }

}

Comment: Divided the Code into 2

Comment: If `EmploymentTable` is not a form datasource, than you need to find this record before check: `super(); employmentTable = SycEmploymentTable::find(...);` Also add this condition to your `if` statement `if (employmentTable.RecId &&  employmentTable.Resigning == dateNull())`

Comment: More likely that `SycEmploymentTable` used as form datasource in your form. In this case you don't need a local variable `EmploymentTable`. Just change `if` statement like this: `if (SycEmploymentTable.Resigning == dateNull())` where `SycEmploymentTable` - your datasource name.